# Build boost.Log on Windows 7

Tags: c++, boost

I recently downloaded http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html but I can't seem to find out how to build it. The rest of my boost lib was installed by using the installer, so all I did was selecting the files I wanted to include.

So how do I build Logs? Building for windows is completely new to me and I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Merge boost.log in the boost directory structure first.

---

Did you build boost ? If not, you have to go to your boost directory, run `boostrap.sh` and then run `b2.exe`. That will build all boost libraries.

Since you are on Windows, boost supports automatic linking, i.e. you just include the header files and the required libraries will be linked automatically when building your project from Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried the .bat file which gave me a b2.exe, maybe that's what you meant? Should I just merge the logs lib into this before building?

Comment: Also, what kind of build will b2 do? Any way of specifying?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you should merge "boost.log" in before.

Comment: By kind of build I think you mean "configuration" in the sense of debug / release ? Yes there is: `variant=debug|release`. `b2 --help` should help more.

Comment: thinking something along the lines http://devsql.blogspot.co.nz/2007/05/building-boost-134-for-x86-x64-and-ia64.html

Comment: do you happen to know what the defaults are if you only run b2 without any flags?

Comment: I think it's release, but I have never tried to make a debug build.